# The comment box is too small

Tags: support, comments

I'm trying to write a comment, however, I found that the box is too small. It makes it difficult to see the entire message I've written.

Is there any way to increase the size of the comment box?

Answer (score 7):

Just pull down the corner!

> [image]

Comment: Although, this is browser specific unless this has been added specifically to SO fields. It wasn't last time I used Edge though. It also isn't showing on my mobile browser.